# Open Website in Facebook Messenger, Set up viewport

Tags: html, css, facebook

When I open my mobile ready (not responsive) website in the FB messenger's own browser it doesn't take my meta viewport tag. That is defined for mobile devices only. Why?

Comment: It's a simple test page, some divs which look good at 980px. So the viewport is set to 980px, but it doesnt take it.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing.